# Numpy element-wise exponentiate every value of matrix A by values in matrix B

Tags: python, numpy

So I have 2 matrices. A = 2x2 and B = 3x2. I'm trying to exponentiate each column respectively of matrix A by the values in matrix B then get the product of each row. So for example,

```
A=[[1,1],[0,0]]
B=[[1,1],[0,0],[2,2]]
```

If we take the first row of A and calculate the value the output will be

```
[[1^1,1^1], [1^0, 1^0], [1^2,1^2]]
```

Then take the product of each row so:

```
[1, 1, 1]
```

Then for the 2nd row

```
[[0^1,0^1],[0^0,0^0],[0^2,0^2]]
```

Product of each row should be

```
[0, 1, 0]
```

The final output should then be

```
[[1,0],[1,1],[1,0]]
```

So for a row A let's say it's 1x2 then each element should be put to the power of row values in matrix B. So column i of row A should be exponentiated by all values in column i of B.

Comment: maybe would be better if you show the matrix operation that you want to reproduce for a general case, or it is just for this particular one?

Comment: How about `(A**B[...,None]).prod(-1)`?

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem that'll work if A ix 1x2, but not 2x2, but this is very close to what I need

Comment: `(A**B[...,None]).prod(-1)` looks right to me? What makes you say it doesn't work with A 2x2?

Comment: @wim I tried coding it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
np.swapaxes(np.product(A[:,np.newaxis,:]**B, axis = -1), 0, 1)
```

gives an output of

```
array([[1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 0]])
```

To understand the steps in this, I suggest you read up on basic slicing and broadcasting in NumPy, while keeping an eye on the array shapes/dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

Your resultant matrix, that I called `C` has the form

```
C[0,0] = (A[0,0]**B[0,0])*(A[0,1]**B[0,1])
C[1,0] = (A[0,0]**B[1,0])*(A[0,1]**B[1,1])
C[2,0] = (A[0,0]**B[2,0])*(A[0,1]**B[2,1])
C[0,1] = (A[1,0]**B[0,0])*(A[1,1]**B[0,1])
C[1,1] = (A[1,0]**B[1,0])*(A[1,1]**B[1,1])
C[2,1] = (A[1,0]**B[2,0])*(A[1,1]**B[2,1])
```

that can be written as

```
C[i,j] = (A[j,0]**B[i,0])*(A[j,1]**B[i,1])
```

So I think that this may work for you, or be adapted to something closer to what you want

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import *

A=np.array([[1,1],[0,0]])
B=np.array([[1,1],[0,0],[2,2]])

C = np.zeros((B.shape[0],A.shape[0]))

for i in range(B.shape[0]):
    for j in range(A.shape[0]):
        C[i,j] = (A[j,0]**B[i,0])*(A[j,1]**B[i,1])
```

The output is as desired

```
print(C)

[[1. 0.]
 [1. 1.]
 [1. 0.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [238]: A=np.array([[1,1],[0,0]])
     ...: B=np.array([[1,1],[0,0],[2,2]])
In [239]: A.shape, B.shape
Out[239]: ((2, 2), (3, 2))
```

Your first row of A

```
In [241]: A[0,:]**B
Out[241]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1]])
```

2nd row:

```
In [242]: A[1,:]**B
Out[242]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [0, 0]])
```

and the products:

```
In [243]: (A[0,:]**B).prod(axis=1)
Out[243]: array([1, 1, 1])
In [244]: (A[1,:]**B).prod(axis=1)
Out[244]: array([0, 1, 0])
```

now with all of `A`:

```
In [245]: (A[:,None]**B)
Out[245]: 
array([[[1, 1],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 1]],

       [[0, 0],
        [1, 1],
        [0, 0]]])
In [246]: (A[:,None]**B).prod(axis=2)
Out[246]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0]])
```

The comment version gets the same numbers, but with a transposed result:

```
In [251]: (A**B[:,:,None]).prod(axis=2)
Out[251]: 
array([[1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 0]])
```

The (2,2) shape of `A` and equal columns creates a bit of ambiguity.

Make a (1,2) array:

```
In [252]: A1 = A[[1],:]
In [253]: A1.shape
Out[253]: (1, 2)
In [254]: (A1[:,None]**B).prod(axis=2)
Out[254]: array([[0, 1, 0]])

In [258]: (A1**B[:,:,None]).prod(axis=2)
Out[258]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [0, 0]])
```